# mean.io initialising new project - owner rights

Tags: node.js, macos, root, meanjs

I'm trying to initialise my first MEAN project with command `mean init myProject`. This command returns the error :

`There are 1313 files in your ~/.npm owned by root
Please change the permissions by running - chown -R whoami ~/.npm`

By running this chown command I have another error `Operation not permitted`.

I tried to use `nvm` but I'm not sure if it's a good direction. If yes I have no idea how to configure it.

Could you please help me with that, I'm struggle with it since couple of days :/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to run chown as root. Get your username using

```
whoami
```

Then run this replacing `<username`> with the one you got in the previous step

```
sudo chown -R <username> ~/.npm
```

For future reference, don't run "npm install -g" commands with sudo. If you're having permission problems, fix those first.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm still getting `Operation not permitted` error

Answer (score 0):

I had really serious problems with mean.io framework/scaffolding tool.

I know, that isn't solution for your problem but please be so kind to consider [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/generators/).